# How to select a location using Google Maps

Tags: maps, geolocation, android, location

I'am developing an Android app where users can add clients specifying a name and a location. The name is required, the location is optional. Under the hood the location is composed of:

- Address as a string
- Latitude (numeric)
- Longitude (numeric)

This is the UI to insert a new client:

[image]

The user types in the name and an optional address.
For the address I was thinking to implement several ways to set it:

- Type in the address manually and then find the location on the map automatically pressing the "find on map" button
- Use the current device position by pressing the "current position" button
- Move the dot on the map and then find out the address automatically

The button "current position" works ok, by pressing it the map and the address field will be set using the current device position (if GPS and internet connection are enabled of course)

The button "find on map" is ambiguous: I'd like it to set the map according to the current address specified by the user in the address field but at the same time I'd like it to do the reverse: take the current position on the map (manually set by the user by scrolling/zooming the map) and geocode the position as an address string and automtically set the address field

I'm struggling to find a good way to implement an easy and straightforward  UI for this "find on map" button. It's not clear what it's doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of the button 'Find On Map' at all.
You could tackle it the following way:- By two way binding the address and the map.

1. When the user types in and selects a location, the input field is filled with the selection as usual + the map auto scrolls to that location.
2. When the user tries to select a location from the map directly by scrolling zooming etc, the input field is populated with the current location of the marker in the map.

This method is implemented in many apps like Uber, Gmaps etc.

Comment: that's a very good solution however I was thinking that this way the user wouldn't be able to refine the position on the map while maintaining the address text. But I guess if Gmaps and Uber are doing so then that's the correct way